# pgfplotstable: how can I change the color of a cell's content while maintaining the style?

Tags: pgfplotstable

I need to change the color of a single cell.

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\pgfplotstabletypeset[
            display columns/0/.style={column type={c},
                column name=\textbf{$Story$}, string type},
            display columns/1/.style={column type={c},
                column name=\textbf{$U_x$}, sci, precision=2},
            display columns/2/.style={column type={c},
                column name=\textbf{$U_y$},sci, precision=2},
            every head row/.style={before row={\toprule},after row=\midrule},
        every last row/.style={after row={\bottomrule}},
            every row 3 column 2/.style={sci,precision=2,
            assign cell content/.style={@cell content=\textcolor{blue}{##1}}
            },
            col sep=&, row sep=\\]{c1 & c2 & c3\\
Story4 & 33.7835 & 33.7878\\
Story3 & 38.4334 & 38.4367\\
Story2 & 37.7156 & 37.7156\\
Story1 & 38.4056 & 38.4034\\}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

but, it seems that the `sci` and`precision` styles don't work, I get:

[image]

what is the correct way to change the color in this context?, my real table is generated using a csv file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I propose the following:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}

\pgfplotstabletypeset[
  columns/c1/.style={column type={c}, column name=Story, string type},
  columns/c2/.style={column type={c}, column name=$U_x$, sci, precision=2},
  columns/c3/.style={column type={c}, column name=$U_y$, sci, precision=2},
  every head row/.style={before row={\toprule}, after row=\midrule},
  every last row/.style={after row={\bottomrule}},
  my special cell/.style={@cell content=\textcolor{blue}{#1}},
  every row 3 column 2/.append style={
    postproc cell content/.append code={%
      \pgfkeysgetvalue{/pgfplots/table/@cell content}{\myTmpVal}%
      \pgfkeysalso{my special cell/.expand once={\myTmpVal}}%
    },
  },
  col sep=&, row sep=\\]{%
c1     & c2      & c3\\
Story4 & 33.7835 & 33.7878\\
Story3 & 38.4334 & 38.4367\\
Story2 & 37.7156 & 37.7156\\
Story1 & 38.4056 & 38.4034\\}

\end{document}
```

[image]

For your specially-colored cell, this uses the following style:

```latex
my special cell/.style={@cell content=\textcolor{blue}{#1}}
```

to which I pass the cell contents *after* `sci` formatting has been applied (the value of `/pgfplots/table/@cell content}` is retrieved at the right time, then passed to the `my special cell` style).

Note that if you replace:

```latex
every row 3 column 2/.append style={
  postproc cell content/.append code={%
    \pgfkeysgetvalue{/pgfplots/table/@cell content}{\myTmpVal}%
    \pgfkeysalso{my special cell/.expand once={\myTmpVal}}%
  },
},
```

with:

```latex
every row 3 column 2/.append style={
  postproc cell content/.append style={
    my special cell=##1,
  },
},
```

you'll see this instead:

[image]

because the first argument of `/pgfplots/table/postproc cell content` is defined as

> the unprocessed input argument as it has been found in the input table

(see *Postprocessing Cell Content* in the [pgfplotstable manual](http://mirrors.ctan.org/graphics/pgf/contrib/pgfplots/doc/pgfplotstable.pdf)).

Regarding your last sentence, you can use a `.csv` file even for your minimal working example, thanks to the `filecontents*` environment of the LaTeX kernel:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{filecontents*}{my-data.csv}
c1     & c2      & c3
Story4 & 33.7835 & 33.7878
Story3 & 38.4334 & 38.4367
Story2 & 37.7156 & 37.7156
Story1 & 38.4056 & 38.4034
\end{filecontents*}

\pgfplotstableread[col sep=&]{my-data.csv}\myLoadedTable

\begin{document}

\pgfplotstabletypeset[
  columns/c1/.style={column type={c}, column name=Story, string type},
  columns/c2/.style={column type={c}, column name=$U_x$, sci, precision=2},
  columns/c3/.style={column type={c}, column name=$U_y$, sci, precision=2},
  every head row/.style={before row={\toprule}, after row=\midrule},
  every last row/.style={after row={\bottomrule}},
  my special cell/.style={@cell content=\textcolor{blue}{#1}},
  every row 3 column 2/.append style={
    postproc cell content/.append code={%
      \pgfkeysgetvalue{/pgfplots/table/@cell content}{\myTmpVal}%
      \pgfkeysalso{my special cell/.expand once={\myTmpVal}}%
    },
  }]{\myLoadedTable}

\end{document}
```

Comment: thanks @frougon, it works!, but not in `string type`, Do I need to do something additional for this type?

Comment: What do you mean? If I take the example from my answer and replace `every row 3 column 2` with `every row 3 column 0`, I get the expected result (“Story1” in blue). Column 0 is `string type` here.

Comment: the previous table is just an example, I have other problems with the real tables that I use, would I put it in another post?

Comment: This may be due to the `.expanded={...}`. Do you have fragile macros in the stuff that causes problem? If you give me one short line to add to the example, I can see and test something, otherwise probably better start a new question.

Comment: Can you try this? `every row 3 column 0/.append style={
    postproc cell content/.append code={\pgfkeysgetvalue{/pgfplots/table/@cell content}{\tmp}\pgfkeysalso{my special cell/.expand once={\tmp}}}}`. It is careful not to expand the special cell's retrieved contents (it only expands a macro whose replacement text is said contents).

Comment: I am not sure, in some cases I have to combine strings with numbers that I must round, for this I use the `siunitx` package, I write something like:  `columns/c3/.style={column type={S}, column name=$U_y$, string type},`

Comment: This looks like a number, so I'm not sure why you need `string type` for such a column...

Comment: I post a new topic in [new topic](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/522040/pgfplotstable-change-the-color-of-a-cells-content-in-string-type-while-maintai), I tried to give a simple example, similar to the example we discuss here