# pgfplotstable: change the color of a cell's content in string type while maintaining the style

Tags: siunitx, pgfplotstable, booktabs

Expanding the topic covered in [pgfplotstable: how can I change the color of a cell's content while maintaining the style?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/521943/pgfplotstable-how-can-i-change-the-color-of-a-cells-content-while-maintaining#521963), correctly resolved by [@frougon](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/73317/frougon), I need to change the color of a single cell in `string style`, I use the `siunitx`to round numbers in `string style` using `type column={S}`.

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\sisetup{
  round-mode          = places,
  round-precision     = 2, % precisión
}

\begin{filecontents*}{my-data.csv}
c1     & c2      & c3
Story4 & 33.7835 & 33.7878
Story3 & 38.4334 & 38.4334
Story2 & 37.7156 & 37.7156
Story1 & 38.4056 & 38.4034
\end{filecontents*}

\pgfplotstableread[col sep=&]{my-data.csv}\myLoadedTable

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\pgfplotstabletypeset[
            display columns/0/.style={column type={c},
                column name=\textbf{$Story$}, string type},
            display columns/1/.style={column type={S},
                column name=\textbf{$U_x$}, string type},
            display columns/2/.style={column type={S},
                column name=\textbf{$U_y$},string type},
            every head row/.style={before row={\toprule},after row=\midrule},
        every last row/.style={after row={\bottomrule}},
            my special cell/.style={@cell content=\textcolor{blue}{#1}},
            every row 3 column 2/.append style={
            postproc cell content/.append style={
            my special cell/.expanded={%
            \pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/table/@cell content}%
            },
            },
        },]{\myLoadedTable}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

when changing the style of a cell, rounding ceases to have an effect, i get:

[image]

Comment: All you need to is to use `my special cell/.style={@cell content=\color{blue}#1}`.

Comment: thanks @Schrödinger'scat, but when I want to apply more styles it seems to not work, for instance:  `my special cell/.style={@cell content=\color{blue}\textbf{#1}}`, it spoils again

Comment: In this case, use `my special cell/.style={@cell content=\color{blue}\bfseries #1}`.

Comment: It doesn't work as expected, it's curious.

Comment: It does, in principle. Add to the options of `\sisetup` the option `detect-weight=true`. Otherwise `siunitx` ignores the font weight.

Comment: Great!, is what I was missing!, thanks a lot @Schrödinger'scat

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you need to is to use `my special cell/.style={@cell content=\color{blue}#1}`.

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\sisetup{
  round-mode          = places,
  round-precision     = 2, % precisión
}

\begin{filecontents*}{my-data.csv}
c1     & c2      & c3
Story4 & 33.7835 & 33.7878
Story3 & 38.4334 & 38.4334
Story2 & 37.7156 & 37.7156
Story1 & 38.4056 & 38.4034
\end{filecontents*}

\pgfplotstableread[col sep=&]{my-data.csv}\myLoadedTable

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\pgfplotstabletypeset[
            display columns/0/.style={column type={c},
                column name=\textbf{$Story$}, string type},
            display columns/1/.style={column type={S},
                column name=\textbf{$U_x$}, string type},
            display columns/2/.style={column type={S},
                column name=\textbf{$U_y$},string type},
            every head row/.style={before row={\toprule},after row=\midrule},
        every last row/.style={after row={\bottomrule}},
            my special cell/.style={@cell content=\color{blue}#1},
            every row 3 column 2/.append style={
            postproc cell content/.append style={
            my special cell/.expanded={%
            \pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/table/@cell content}%
            },
            },
        },]{\myLoadedTable}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

**ADDENDUM**: If you want to play with the font weight and so on, you may want to instruct `siunitx` not to ignore you. One way of doing that is to add the `detect-all=true` option to `\sisetup`.

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\sisetup{
  round-mode          = places,
  round-precision     = 2, % precisión
  detect-all=true
}

\begin{filecontents*}{my-data.csv}
c1     & c2      & c3
Story4 & 33.7835 & 33.7878
Story3 & 38.4334 & 38.4334
Story2 & 37.7156 & 37.7156
Story1 & 38.4056 & 38.4034
\end{filecontents*}

\pgfplotstableread[col sep=&]{my-data.csv}\myLoadedTable

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\pgfplotstabletypeset[
            display columns/0/.style={column type={c},
                column name=\textbf{$Story$}, string type},
            display columns/1/.style={column type={S},
                column name=\textbf{$U_x$}, string type},
            display columns/2/.style={column type={S},
                column name=\textbf{$U_y$},string type},
            every head row/.style={before row={\toprule},after row=\midrule},
        every last row/.style={after row={\bottomrule}},
            my special cell/.style={@cell content=\color{blue}\bfseries#1},
            every row 3 column 2/.append style={
            postproc cell content/.append style={
            my special cell/.expanded={%
            \pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/table/@cell content}%
            },
            },
        },]{\myLoadedTable}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Please note that I updated the [other answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/521963/73317) to use the `\pgfkeysgetvalue{/pgfplots/table/@cell content}{...}` approach rather than `my special cell/.expanded={...}` in order to retrieve cell contents *without expanding it to early,* before wrapping it inside `\textcolor`.

It appears to be possible to use `siunitx` with `pgfplotstable`,<sup>1</sup> however `siunitx` is not mentioned in the `pgfplotstable` manual. Thus, for now, I'll only propose the approach mentioned there, which is to use `/pgfplots/table/dec sep align`. By default, this uses horizontal centering inside the column, but you can sepcify a different alignment type with `dec sep align=l` or `dec sep align=r`. Here we go. :-)

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{filecontents*}{my-data.csv}
c1     & c2      & c3
Story4 & 33.7835 & 33.7878
Story3 & 38.4334 & 38.4334
Story2 & 37.7156 & 37.7156
Story1 & 38.4056 & 38.4034
\end{filecontents*}

\pgfplotstableread[col sep=&]{my-data.csv}\myLoadedTable

\begin{document}

\pgfplotstabletypeset[
  my numeric col/.style={fixed, fixed zerofill, precision=2, dec sep align},
  columns/c1/.style={column type={c}, column name=\textbf{Story}, string type},
  columns/c2/.style={my numeric col, column name=$U_x$},
  columns/c3/.style={my numeric col, column name=$U_y$},
  every head row/.style={before row={\toprule},after row=\midrule},
  every last row/.style={after row={\bottomrule}},
  my special cell/.style={@cell content=\textcolor{blue}{#1}},
  every row 3 column 2/.append style={
    postproc cell content/.append code={%
      \pgfkeysgetvalue{/pgfplots/table/@cell content}{\myTmpCellContents}%
      \pgfkeysalso{my special cell/.expand once={\myTmpCellContents}}%
    },
  }]{\myLoadedTable}

\end{document}
```

### [image]

**Footnote**

1. See the [answer of Schrödinger's cat](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/522043/73317)!

Comment: It seems to be better, I'll try it, thanks a lot again for your time

Comment: You're welcome, it's good to have both methods here. For a new user, you've provided decent minimal working examples, thanks to you. :-)