Applying conditional formatting in \pgfplotstabletypeset resets other formats
My MWE is shown below,
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{tikz}%
\usetikzlibrary{calc}%
\usepackage{ifthen}
\usepackage{pgfplots, pgfplotstable} %
\usepackage{amsmath}
\newcommand\sols{0} 

\begin{document}

\pgfplotstableread{
    Height  Uncertainty T1      T2      T3      tav     tsqr
    0.5     0.2         0.33    0.28    0.3     0.3     0.09
    1       0.2         0.44    0.47    0.47    0.46    0.2116
    1.5     0.2         0.53    0.55    0.57    0.55    0.3025
    2       0.2         0.65    0.62    0.65    0.64    0.4096
    2.5     0.2         0.69    0.72    0.73    0.71    0.5041
    3       0.2         0.79    0.76    0.8     0.78    0.6084
}\datatablePracA

\pgfplotstabletypeset[columns={Height,T1, T2, T3, tav, tsqr},
columns/Height/.style={
    fixed,fixed zerofill,precision=1,
    column type=c,
    column name=Height (m) $\pm 0.2$, head row/.style={ @cell content=\textcolor{white}{##1}}
},
columns/tav/.style={
    fixed,fixed zerofill,precision=2,
    column type=c,
    column name=$t_{\text{av.}}$ (s),
    assign cell content/.code={
            \ifthenelse{\sols=1}
            {\pgfkeyssetvalue{/pgfplots/table/@cell content}{\textcolor{red}{##1}}
                }
            {\pgfkeyssetvalue{/pgfplots/table/@cell content}{\textcolor{white}{##1}}
                }
    },
}
]{\datatablePracA}
\end{document}

I am trying to turn the tav values to white when solutions are off, and red when solutions are on. The only problem is that I lose the fixed,fixed zerofill,precision=2, formatting. How do I keep the correct precision?

It's not because of the colors. In the documentation section 3.2 Typesetting Cell Content The argument #1 is the (unformatted)
contents of the input table.

With this post? https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/521943/pgfplotstable-how-can-i-change-the-color-of-a-cells-content-while-maintaining

Or this https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/522040/pgfplotstable-change-the-color-of-a-cells-content-in-string-type-while-maintai/522043#522043

The solutions in those questions work, but I am looking for something akin to my special column/.style so that i can format whole columns at a time.

If I understood correctly, depending on the \sols parameter, we put the solutions in red.
I propose to create a boolean and \mycolor.
Then I use what was described in the post pgfplotstable: change the color of a cell's content in string type while maintaining the style
    \documentclass{article}
    \usepackage{amsthm}
    % \usepackage{tikz}%
    % \usetikzlibrary{calc}%
    \usepackage{ifthen}
    \usepackage{pgfplots, pgfplotstable} %
    \usepackage{amsmath}
    % \newcommand\sols{1}
    \newboolean{sols}
    \setboolean{sols}{true}%<-- or false
    \ifthenelse{\boolean{sols}}%
    {\colorlet{mycolor}{red}}
    {\colorlet{mycolor}{white}}

    \begin{document}

    \pgfplotstableread{
    Height  Uncertainty T1      T2      T3      tav     tsqr
    0.5     0.2         0.33    0.28    0.3     0.3     0.09
    1       0.2         0.44    0.47    0.47    0.46    0.2116
    1.5     0.2         0.53    0.55    0.57    0.55    0.3025
    2       0.2         0.65    0.62    0.65    0.64    0.4096
    2.5     0.2         0.69    0.72    0.73    0.71    0.5041
    3       0.2         0.79    0.76    0.8     0.78    0.6084
    }\datatablePracA

    \pgfplotstabletypeset[columns={Height,T1, T2, T3, tav, tsqr},
    columns/Height/.style={
    fixed,fixed zerofill,precision=1,
    column type=c,
    column name=Height (m) $\pm 0.2$, head row/.style={ @cell content=\textcolor{white}{##1}}
    },
    columns/tav/.style={
    fixed,fixed zerofill,precision=2,
    column type=c,
    column name=$t_{\text{av.}}$ (s),
    %     assign cell content/.code={
    my special cell/.style={@cell content=\color{mycolor}##1},
    postproc cell content/.append style={
                    my special cell/.expanded={%
                    \pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/table/@cell content}%
                    },
    },
    }
    ]{\datatablePracA}
    \end{document}



Yes, this works perfectly. I can even keep \newcommand\sols{0}    \ifthenelse{\sols=1}  as this is used elsewhere in the document
